# Password protect disk images on Mac from deleting

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-utility, password, dmg

I know that I can create a password protected dmg file with more folders in it. But I want to know if there's a way through which I can prevent any action on the dmg file itself. Because right now, if anyone wants to delete the dmg file - which contains a whole lot of backup - they can do so without having to enter the password. I want to have to enter a password to rename, delete, move the dmg file without it having opened.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the **.dmg** file from being deleted without explicit permission, you need to set the **ACL** permissions for the file to not be deleted. In **Terminal** use, e.g.:

```
sudo chmod +a "everyone deny delete" foobar.dmg
```

Once set, if you try to **rename**, **delete**, or **move** the **.dmg** file, e.g. in **Finder**, you'll have to enter Administrator credentials, or in **Terminal** use `sudo`, which requires the same level of credentials too, to do the same.

---

In **Terminal**, have a look at the manual page for `chmod`, e.g., type `man chmod` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or just type `chmod` and right-click on it selecting, **Open man Page**.

- In general, I'd read then entire man page however, the section titled
   **ACL MANIPULATION OPTIONS** is the relevant one to focus on.

To see what **ACL** permissions are set on a file/folder,  use, e.g.:

```
$ ls -le foobar.dmg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  100020736 Dec  7 09:21 foobar.dmg
0: group:everyone deny delete
$
```